# Prevent Duplicate Request IDs While Inserting Into Table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have two tables T1 (Header Table) and T2 (Details Table). T1 consists only one row for each request ID which has status as below:

```
ID-1    1234    ABCD   IN_PROCESS
ID-2    2345    XYZ    APPROVED
```

Where, T2 consists data as follows:

```
ID-1    1234    APPROVER-1
ID-1    1234    APPROVER-2
ID-2    2345    APPROVER-1
ID-2    2345    APPROVER-2
ID-2    2345    APPROVER-3
```

Can you PL/SQL experts help me with insert statement for T2 in order to avoid duplicates?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ankit Vyas

Comment: Create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on desired fields!

Comment: So you want an INSERT statement that prevents further insertion of duplicate values in table2? I can not see that they are duplicates. Please elaborate on your issue further.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates"? All records in T2 are distinct.

Comment: Please, provide column names and roles and reference them in your text description not to guess what is the request ID and what is the relationship between tables.

Comment: Dear all, duplicate in terms of insertion. I validated insertion of duplication on T1 by adding primary key on Request ID. But my scheduled insertion program was inserting new records from T1 and duplicate rows (from T1 only). So in order to achieve the mentioned requirement, I inserted data into T1 and commit, then I wrote insert statement of T2 with condition (Request ID not in T2) and commit. So ultimately, it fulfilled my requirement.